# Locally storing a javascript variable which is incremented by .php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, save, local-storage

I have a javascript variable which is incremented in a .php script, there is no problem in that except the .php script makes the page reload which then resets the variable, my question is then, is it possible to locally store a javascript variable even though the whole increment happens in a .php script and the variable and the local storage is in the html script with the variable and the function, the html/javascript file and the .php file is separated which is the hard part.

html/javascript:

```
<div class="bidVar">
  current amount: $<span id="bidVar"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var bidVar= 1;
  document.getElementById("bidVar").innerHTML = bidVar;
  document.getElementByID("bidVar").value = bidVar;

  function addToCurrent() {
    bidVar= bidVar+ 1 ;
    document.getElementById("bidVar").innerHTML = bidVar;
  }
</script>
```

.php:

```
<?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> addToCurrent(); </script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in the local storage is **not** incremented by PHP: your PHP script outputs some Javascript code that does it.
You either have not to redirect directly in your PHP script, or to redirect with something indicating that the next page should increment the variable.

Example :

*script.php*

```
// ...
header('Location: mypage.php?increment=true');
exit();
```

*mypage.php*

```
// ...
if (isset($_GET['increment']) && $_GET['increment'] == true) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> addToCurrent(); </script>';
}
// ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the variable still ind the same script and then instead have a function in the .php script which redirects to another page, which then increments the variable and then redirects to the first page with the actual variable in it?

Answer (score 0):

To keep from refreshing the page, and therefore reloading your JavaScript, you will probably want to look into an AJAX styled page.  That way specific parts of the page can be reloaded or manipulated, JavaScript variables can be tweaked, but the entire page never reloads.

If that is not a possibility, you will have to have your JavaScript send its current count when a link is clicked or form submitted, have your PHP catch that number, and then your PHP send the current count to your JavaScript when the page reloads.